# Is there a word for the act of carrying out the subject of a particular web comic drawing or sketch offline?

Tags: single-word-requests

In the section "[Inspired Activities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xkcd#Inspired_activities)" of the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xkcd#) on the web comic [xkcd](https://xkcd.com/), there are a number of occasions during which people have carried out the subject of one of the comics offline. The first three examples include:

- Richard Stallman was confronted by students dressed as ninjas before speaking at the Yale Political Union – inspired by "[Open Source](https://xkcd.com/225/)".
- On September 23, 2007, hundreds of people gathered at Reverend Thomas J. Williams Park, 42.39561°N 71.13051°W, in North Cambridge, Massachusetts, whose coordinates were mentioned in "[Dream Girl](https://xkcd.com/240/)". Munroe appeared, commenting, "Maybe wanting something does make it real", reversing the conclusion he drew in the last frame of the same strip. Cory Doctorow wearing a red cape and a pair of goggles based on his appearance in xkcd. Doctorow later wore the costume again while accepting a Hugo Award on Munroe's behalf.
- When animated xkcd strip "[Time](https://xkcd.com/1190/)" won a Hugo Award for Best Graphic Story in August 2014, it was accepted by Cory Doctorow on behalf of Munroe, dressing as Munroe had drawn him in an earlier strip, "[1337: Part 5](https://xkcd.com/345/)".

I wonder the act of carrying out such web comics in the physical world has a name. I know there are [Comic Cons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comic_book_convention) (Comic Book Conventions) during which many people dress up as their favourite comic book heroes. However, this is not what I have in mind. The word should pertain to the act of carrying out one specific web comic drawing or sketch, not to impersonating a character of a comic as a whole.

> **Question**: do such offline enactments of the subject of particular web comic drawing or sketch have a word in the English language?

Comment: Something similar to *dramatisation*, *staging* or *acting out* might describe people deliberately staging scenes or events from a comic, but you seem to want something far more specific. I doubt there's a widely-known term that most people would understand, but there might be one in XKCD fandom or another niche community.

Comment: There's a hypernym: **reify**: <<  [transitive verb]: to consider or represent (something abstract) as a material or concrete thing : to give definite content and form to (a concept or idea) >> [[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reify)] // << to make something more real or consider it as real:
_These phenomena are reified into facts_. >> [[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/reify)].

Comment: What about [cosplay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosplay), the practice of dressing up as a character from a film, book, or video game ?